# jquery selectors second selector not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I cannot understand why the second `$("tr:even").css("color","yellow");`
doesn't work when the first one works correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button61").click(function(){
        $("tr:even").css("background-color","purple");
        $("tr:even").css("color","yellow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should apply the style to the table cells (since they cover the row) :

```
$("tr:even td").css({ "background-color": "purple", "color" : "yellow" });
```

as a sidenote: use `css()` method just once with an object as argument, or even better just assign a classname like so

```
$("tr:even").addClass('highlight');
```

and define your style in the css

```
.highlight td {
   background-color: purple;
   color: yellow;
}
```

so you can keep off css from javascript, for an improved code mantainance.

Answer (score 0):

It does work - here's a demo of the following JS: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimdotdotdot/UySzs/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button61").click(function(){
        $("tr:even").css("background-color","purple");
        $("tr:even").css("color","yellow");
    });
});
```

But like others have said, just do it all in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code, it's alright. Make sure you didn't do any typos. Otherwise explain it clearly if u still have problem. Check console(press F12) for script errors..